# I deleted some core data generated files from the project, but Xcode still tries to compile them

Tags: ios, core-data, xcode8

I deleted the Objective-C files that Core Data generated from the data model, so I could go back to the swift files that I had generated in Xcode 7. When deleting the files, I had the files moved to the trash, and added the swift files back in to the project. I'm using Xcode 8.0.

The error I get is

> "error: no such file or directory", for the missing files, one of
>   which is 
>   Luna.build/DerivedSources/CoreDataGenerated/Luna/.LunaObservation+CoreDataClass.m.
>   There are corresponding errors for
>   LunaObservation+CoreDataProperties.m and LunaOrbit+CoreDataClass.m,
>   but not LunaOrbit+CoreDataProperties.m.

I don't see the file's name in the build phase's compile sources. I've tried cleaning the project and deleting the derived data without success.

**Update:** I finally figured out how to generate Swift files instead of Objective-C files, but I'm still getting the error that it's looking for the deleted Objective-C files.

**Update #2:** I was able to reduce the number of errors after cleaning the project and deleting the entire derived data file; I no longer get errors for the missing .m and .h files, but I do get a single error about two missing files: .Orbit+CoreDataProperties.swift and .Observation+CoreDataProperties.swift. These files exist, but they don't have the period in front of the name. Attempting to add the period to the file name results in a "Rename failed" message. Both files had an extra "import" after the others that didn't import anything--the line just ended.

The post [XCode 8 generates broken NSManagedObject subclasses for iOS 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39657231/xcode-8-generates-broken-nsmanagedobject-subclasses-for-ios-10) shows pretty much the problem I'm having.

Answer (score 2):

In the Data Model inspector, try setting the Module option to "Current Product Module" (instead of Global Namespace). This will add the period to the generated NSManagedObject subclass name.

[image]

You can see the result of this action by looking in the Configuration section. The class name will be prefixed with the period.

[image]

A more detail response can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40647786/4748172